# Getting parts within a String with a Regular Expression

Tags: vb.net

Here is an example:

```
Dim myString As String = "£/GrocerySMilk:Potatoes:Garlic£/Grocery:Tomatoes:Salad:Bread£/Grocery"
```

I need to get parts starting with `£/GroceryS` and ending with `£/Grocery`.

Following the example, those parts:

1. `Milk:Potatoes:Garlic`
2. and `Tomatoes:Salad:Bread`

Since it could be an undefined number of parts to get, I need to use a regular expression.

What I have tried:

```
Sub showMatch(ByVal text As String, ByVal expr As String)
    Console.WriteLine("My regular expression: " + expr)
    Dim collection As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(text, expr)
    Dim match As Match

    For Each match In collection
        Console.WriteLine(match)
    Next match
End Sub

Sub Main()
    Dim myString As String = "£/GrocerySMilk:Potatoes:Garlic£/Grocery:Tomatoes:Salad:Bread£/Grocery"
    Console.WriteLine("Matching words that start with '£/GroceryS' and ends with '£/Grocery'")
    showMatch(myString, "£/GroceryS(.*?)£/Grocery")
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

Comment: *I have tried other variants but nothing works yet.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Regex pattern `(.*?)£\/GroceryS?:?` extracts those parts in the first group of each match.

```vb
Sub Main()
    Dim myString = "£/GrocerySMilk:Potatoes:Garlic£/Grocery:Tomatoes:Salad:Bread£/Grocery"
    Dim ptrn = "(.*?)£\/GroceryS?:?"

    Console.WriteLine("Matching words that start with '£/GroceryS' and ends with '£/Grocery'")
    showMatch(myString, ptrn)
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub

Sub showMatch(ByVal text As String, ByVal expr As String)
    Console.WriteLine($"My regular expression: {expr}")

    For Each m As Match In Regex.Matches(text, expr, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
        Console.WriteLine(m.Groups(1).Value)
    Next
End Sub
```

Here's an [online test](https://regex101.com/r/Ou5ruY/26)

Comment: Or `dim pattern = "£\/GroceryS?:?" dim result = Regex.Split(input, pattern).Where(function(s) not string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToArray()`.

Comment: @Jimi Nice one. Thank you.

Comment: @dr.null Thanks to both of you. You saved the day!